# Javascript to enter data into name cards

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a name card under a class and id named "column" . I have used the clone function with a for loop in JavaScript to increase the number of name cards so that i don't have to retype the code every time I create a new card. How do i access each name card and Enter/Edit the data inside each name card using JavaScript? Where ever i need to Enter data i have entered "DATA HERE" in the code below. At the moment I have 8 name cards using the clone property. As i am new to this, i don't know if this is the best way to do this. If there is a better way please let me know. Thanks a lot.

MAIN GOAL: i want to show different data in different name cards, but i don't want to rewrite the HTML code for each name card as the HTML code becomes very long.  For example Name card 1 will have different data to name card 2.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $('.column');
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      e.clone().insertAfter(e);
      e.clone[i].attr('id', 'clone' + i++);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column" id="column">

       <div class="container">

       <div class="header">  <h3>"DATA HERE"  </h3>   </div>
                              
                              
                         
  <div class="location">
     <h1><ion-icon class ="icon1" name="location-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon> "DATA HERE" </h1>
  </div> 
             
              
  <form method="post" > <p>                                
       <button type="button" class="button3"> LIGHTS</button></a>                    
       <a href="DATA HERE"><button class="button">ON</button></a>  </p>                                             
  </form>
                               
        

  <form method="post" >  <p>                                                
       <a href="DATA HERE"><button type="button" class="button2">OFF</button></a> </p>                                                        
  </form>
        
        
              <div class="icon-bar">
              <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a> 
              <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE" </a> 
              <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a> 
              <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>                 
              </div>
                      
            
               <div class="icon-bar2">
               <a class="active" href="#"> "DATA HERE" </a> 
               <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a> 
               <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>                                  
               </div>


        
               </div>                      
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now, you can use `querySelectorAll` to find the .column class, then you can set your code to each selector with it's index, starting from 0 to the 1st and ends with 7 in your case ..

here is an example for what i mean
try the snippet

**EDIT**: changed the snippet with all required areas.

here is an example of all content control on the 1st container, you can use what you need

Try the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = $('.column');
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    e.clone().insertAfter(e);

  }
  //selecting the first Container with variables
  const allcls = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
  const chld = allcls[0].querySelector('.header > h3');
  const chld2 = allcls[0].querySelector('.location > h1');
  const chld3 = allcls[0].querySelectorAll('form');
  const frmchld = chld3[0].querySelector('p :nth-child(2)');
  const frmchld2 = chld3[1].querySelector('p :nth-child(1)');
  const chld4 = allcls[0].querySelectorAll('.icon-bar .active');
  const chld5 = allcls[0].querySelectorAll('.icon-bar2 .active');
  /* set data for each element */
  //.header text with new style
  chld.innerText = "New Text for Header";
  chld.style.color = 'gray';
  chld.style.textAlign = 'center';
  chld.style.margin = 'auto';
  chld.style.padding = '1rem';
  chld.style.background = 'darkblue';
  chld.style.width = 'max-content';
  chld.style.border = '1px solid darkgray';
//.location text with new color
  chld2.innerText = 'Location text';
  chld2.style.color = 'darkblue';
//ON button link + name
  frmchld.setAttribute('onClick', '#NEWLINK_FOR_ON');
  frmchld.innerText = "ON Button";
//off button link + name  
  frmchld2.setAttribute('onClick', '#NEWLINK2_FOR_ON');
  frmchld2.innerText = "OFF Button";
//icon-bar links ( names + href )
  chld4[0].innerText = "Iconbar Link1";
  chld4[1].innerText = 'Iconbar link2';
  chld4[2].innerText = 'Iconbar link3';
  chld4[3].innerText = 'Iconbar link4';
  chld4[0].setAttribute('href', '#Link_1');
  chld4[1].setAttribute('href', '#Link_2');
  chld4[2].setAttribute('href', '#Link_3');
  chld4[3].setAttribute('href', '#Link_4');
//icon-bar2 links ( names + href )
  chld5[0].innerText = "Iconbar2 Link1";
  chld5[1].innerText = 'Iconbar2 link2';
  chld5[2].innerText = 'Iconbar2 link3';
  chld5[0].setAttribute('href', '#Link_1');
  chld5[1].setAttribute('href', '#Link_2');
  chld5[2].setAttribute('href', '#Link_3');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column" id="column">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
      <h3>"DATA HERE" </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="location">
      <h1>
        <ion-icon class="icon1" name="location-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon> "DATA HERE" </h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="button3"> LIGHTS</button>
        <button class="button" onClick="#">ON</button> </p>
    </form>



    <form method="post">
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="button2" onClick="#">OFF</button> </p>
    </form>


    <div class="icon-bar">
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE" </a>
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>
    </div>


    <div class="icon-bar2">
      <a class="active" href="#"> "DATA HERE" </a>
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>
      <a class="active" href="#">"DATA HERE"</a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks,  this is just printing text into the middle of the HTML page

Comment: i had just added text to the 1st clone , [0] goes for the 1st clone try to change it to any from 0-7 and you will understand =)

Comment: Hey bro thanks . It doesnt seem to work for me :(  . I also tried giving an ID to the first header and used    

allcls[0].document.getElementById("Trailer_name").innerHTML = "HI";   and still it does not change

Comment: you have to learn more about [JS Nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)

Comment: read more about [JQuery childs](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp)

Comment: Hey @Burham B Soliman, thanks a lot man. Sorry for the very late reply. This solution seems to be working very well for me. But if the form had the "action" with it how would you select the action? because i need to put a link inside the action. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: you can select attribute using dom or jquery, 
for dom `YOUR_ELEMENT.setAttribute('action', 'YOUR_NEW_ATTRIBUTE');`
for jquery, `$('YOUR_SELECTOR').attr('action', 'YOUR_NEW_ATTRIBUTE');`

Comment: Yes Thankss, i got it now. But for some reason i had to remove the Query selector all from the form

Comment: the `querySelectorAll` returns all results in array, so you can call each using array index starting from [0] for the first element and ends by the length of array so you can choose which element you need by using the selector index like `element[0]`, `element[1]` .. etc. so you need it to define the element that you are applying your code on it

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the final porpose of your problem, but i'm assuming you are trying to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var e = document.getElementById("column");
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  var newe=e.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newe);
  newe.id="column"+i;
}
```

hope it helps, probably you are learning but if the data comes from a database this workaround you are trying doing is usless (you will print trough a function this HTML.
Keep Growing, **Plus Ultra!!!**

Comment: Hey man, thanks for replying. I now have 8 name cards produced with that for loop. I just need to access them individually to change the data inside each of them. Thanks